# How to remove double tap to zoom feature on AVPlayerViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

AVPlayerViewController zooms in when double tapped while playing a video. I am looking to make a snapchat story-like player. I have removed the player controls and now the only thing different from snapchat is that it zooms when double tapped. How can I remove the double tap without disabling user interaction? I still need to recognize touches to move on to the next video like snapchat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `UIView` as `subView` with clear `backgroundColor` to player's view and add your required gesture on that view.Like following.

```
[playerViewController.view addSubview:YourView];
```

Comment: Genius. Thanks. Late night not sure why I couldn't think of that.

Comment: The reason this was not working was because I was presenting the avPlayerViewController instead of just adding it as a subview of the super viewController. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

The option:

```
playerViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

is working, this answer shouldn't be downvoted!

The behaviour in iOS 10: when you disable user interaction on AVPlayerViewController and then add gesture recognizer:

```
_moviePlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
_moviePlayer.view.frame = _backgroundContainer.frame;
_moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UtilsViewFlexibleElement;
_moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_moviePlayer.showsPlaybackControls = NO;

[_moviePlayer.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped)]];
```

the gesture will be registered and fully working.

Answer (score 3):

```
playerViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```